# spring mvc: inject servlet context

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-mvc

Good day!

I develop a spring mvc application. I use annotations @Controller and @RequestMapping but avoid @Autowired, so I create in my context.xml a bean associated with my controller and inject to it all required beans.

Now I want to access a context-param from web.xml. To do this I implement a ServletContextAware interface. But after I implemented it, all my request mappings stop working. Here is log:

```
Jul 24, 2013 6:25:15 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT//admin/attrManager/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcherServlet'
```

If I delete "implements ServletContextAware" then all works fine. Why does it occurs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: any reason for implementing ServletContextAware? may I know the specific business scenario? from what part you are getting request like "/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT//admin/attrManager/" and is there any mapping specified for that?

Comment: Do you have any exception on startup?

Comment: >>any reason for implementing ServletContextAware? I want to read some constants from web.xml, that are in <context-param> tag.

Comment: >>from what part you are getting request like "/web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/admin/attrManager/" I just write this request in browser. So, SpringDispatcherServlet handles all requests and my controller is annotated with @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/attrManager"). And I have a method annotated with @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)

Comment: You can just add ServletContext as parameter to your Method in which you want to access ServletContext param attribute instead of implementing ServletContextAware interface, Spring will inject ServletContext object to that method parameter.

Comment: Also, why do you avoid `@Autowired`?

Comment: >> why do you avoid @Autowired? - I like xml ;) You can see usages of all your beans in one file. And it is inconveniently to use @Autowired if you need more then one instances of the same class.